# How to connect to MySQL database which is present on Azure Virtual Machine using Azure logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

How to connect to MySQL database which is present on Azure Virtual Machine using Azure logic app?

How to connect to MySQL database which is present on Azure Virtual Machine using Azure logic app? Is this possible without ISE? ISE is being retired in 2024. Are there any alternatives of ISE?

Comment: Could you please share you workflow/ design to understand the problem better?

Comment: Naveen Sharma, Nothing much. Just need to get row from MySQL database using logic app. Only catch is this MySQL is present on Azure Virtual Machine and there is no on-premise data gateway. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Have you tried any approach where got any errors/blockers? If so then share details that will help more on this ask here.

Comment: Tried using logic app inbuilt MySQL connector, but it is asking for gateway which is mandatory. Since no gateway is there not able to proceed further. link of connector learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/mysql . Please let me know if there is any other way to proceed.

Comment: You can create a [VPN gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways) on your VM's virtual network and use it in MySQL connector gateway section.